# Checking the completion of Android background thread

Tags: android, multithreading

After loading the first activity, my application immediately starts downloading some files in a background process (I use `new Thread()` for this).

In the first activity, there is also a button which opens the second activity. It is crucial for the second activity that the background download is finished.

My task:

If user clicks on the button while the background download is not yet finished, the application must wait and not open the second activity. It must show a message like "Please wait" instead.
If in XX seconds after clicking download is not finished either, another message (with OK button) appears: "You have a too slow connection."

Comment: The proper way to do this is via Handler. Handler on the UI thread can handle messages being passed via separate threads. Create your thread and make sure it has reference to your handler. When the download is finished, send a message to the handler using it's reference. Look up the documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

Have your thread broadcast a "completed" action to the main thread and stash this result.
Then on the UI thread you can check this variable to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

you can check using

```
Thread myThread; //your thread that is downloading thigns
if(myThread.isAlive())
{
    //do what you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AsyncTask for this. 
Using its override methods.